# Meteor.js on login event

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I'm rather new to the meteor framework and JavaScript in general, but I'm working on a little project using the framework to try and bring myself up to scratch. Basically I'm working on a micro blogging site.

At the moment users are able to log in through several services, fb, google etc. And I retrieve their avatars via the service id inserted into the needed url, all this works fine. But I want the user to be able to see their own avatar as soon as they log in which means I need to run some JavaScript right after login is successful. At this point in time I cant find anything on an onLogin style event. And have hacked together a handlebars template to run the code when a user logs in. However this code appears to only run once and if a user logs out and then back in they don't see their avatar anymore.

Does anyone know of an event I can use to do this?

here is my hacky template

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    {{> userInput}}
{{/if}}
```

here is the js it calls

```
$('#inputAvatar').css('background-image', 'url('+avatarUrl+')');
```

I would really appreciate the help, I'm sure it's something simple that I've overlooked but I cant seem to figure it out!

Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if the way you're doing it is the most appropriate but personally do the following on the client side to detect if a user logged in:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  if(Meteor.userId()){
    //do your stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, knew it was something obvious! The code runs fine now, but for some reason my code to update the background image isn't working. I'll note it works when entering it into chromes console but not when run from within the Deps.autorun method

`$('#inputAvatar').css('background-image', 'url(\'+avatarURL+'\')');`

Comment: **UPDATE** I actually solved the problem with the .rendered function for my template combined with the Deps.autorun function. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can i ask why you need to run this on the client? It is now actually really confusing me with what Metoer.userId() does on the server.

Comment: `Deps` has been renamed to `Tracker`.  So this is now [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using google login or any other o-auth login, you can pass a callback function which will gets execute after login,

Here is the sample code.

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
  requestPermissions: ['email']
}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error); //If there is any error, will get error here
  }else{
    console.log(Meteor.user());// If there is successful login, you will get login details here
  }
});
```

Comment: Callbacks should be available to any Meteor.loginWith<Service>() method, including Meteor.loginWithPassword(). I don't want the reference to OAuth throwing anyone off here. 
https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWithPassword