# how to find the currentUser on a login attempt

Tags: authentication, meteor

I'm trying to add a simple handler to process a user on logging in.
I thought this would be simple but ... for some reason I cannot get at the user in the Accounts.onLogin callback.

```
Meteor.startup ->
  if Meteor.isServer

    Accounts.onLogin ->
      console.log("login | onLogin")
      user = Meteor.user()
      console.log("login | onLogin user:", user)
```

but this never reaches the second console.log.

if i comment out `user = Meteor.user()` then it doesn't crash.

is it possible to get at the currentUser in this way from server-side meteor?

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin

For client side I could listen with a tracker, 
however I would prefer to work with this in a callback event and server side.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16353336/1146785

The odd thing is the error always refers to Meteor.userId() even though i'm not calling that.

```
I20150109-05:49:02.924(-8)? Exception in onLogin callback: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
I20150109-05:49:02.925(-8)?     at Object.Meteor.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:19:1)
I20150109-05:49:02.926(-8)?     at Object.Meteor.user (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:24:1)
I20150109-05:49:02.927(-8)?     at packages/dcsan:mpg/both/startup/AccountsValidation.coffee:43:21
I20150109-05:49:02.928(-8)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
I20150109-05:49:02.929(-8)?     at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:121:1
I20150109-05:49:02.930(-8)?     at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:112:1
I20150109-05:49:02.931(-8)?     at [object Object]._.extend.each (packages/callback-hook/hook.js:102:1)
I20150109-05:49:02.932(-8)?     at successfulLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:111:1)
I20150109-05:49:02.933(-8)?     at attemptLogin (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:283:1)
I20150109-05:49:02.934(-8)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.login (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:436:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing something here-
`Accounts.onLogin` has parameter User object `userObject` and user details can be access via `userObject.user` , use following -

```
Accounts.onLogin (userObject)->
 # userObject.user object can get you currently successful logged in user 
 console.log("login | onLogin")
 console.log("login | onLogin user:", userObject.user)
```

Comment: that works! still, its odd that you can't get the Meteor.user() within the onLogin callback. i guess its not set up in the lifecycle then.

Comment: Basically, on Meteor Server side, you can have access to user object only with `this.userId` but the code you are using cannot have even that. you access it using object passed